# Launch request ignored, instance already running

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have created a scheduled task that runs every minute, indefinitely.

The task launches a batch which moves files between 2 servers. It runs with a specific domain account.

The task takes up to 10 seconds to finish.

When the task is scheduled for the first time, it works correctly for several hours. At some point it starts launching n instances of the same task and many of them fails as you can see below. After few hours the launched instances are 2 or 3, but then it reaches up to 9 instences.

[image: problematic run]

Then if I modify the task and save it (without modifying anything actually), it runs correctly for few days again.

[image: correct run]

Same task used to work correctly on Windows Server 2012 R2. I've troubles with Windows Server 2019 and 2022

**1st fixing attempt**

Modifying the task  "for a duration of" and setting 1 day instead of indefinitely seems to have 99.9% solved the problem
[image: task "for a duration of"]

Now the error occurs only when the run time coincides with the one defined in the trigger
[image: log overview]